# How to make my Screen Scrollable with ListView / Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, scrollable

i cant seem to work my way around this i cant make it scrollable tried all the solution but i am getting errors in every method so decided to post my code here and hope someone will report the code with listview scrollable page same code the current error i am getting is this:

Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
Null check operator used on a null value
The relevant error-causing widget was
ListView
lib\signup.dart:17
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
Null check operator used on a null value
The relevant error-causing widget was
ListView

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:property_records/constraint.dart';

class Signup extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SizedBox(
        height: 200.0,
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/pr.png'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "Register Now",
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.lock,
                            color: KPrimaryColor,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Your Name")),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.email,
                            color: KPrimaryColor,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Email Address")),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.lock,
                            color: KPrimaryColor,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Password")),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.lock,
                            color: KPrimaryColor,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Confirm Password")),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.lock,
                            color: KPrimaryColor,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Mobile Number")),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.lock,
                            color: KPrimaryColor,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Office Name")),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Spacer(),
                    FittedBox(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 150),
                        child: Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 36, vertical: 16),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                            color: KPrimaryColor,
                          ),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                "Sign Up",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Icon(
                                Icons.arrow_forward,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please improve code quality, the provided code is a mess?

Comment: i just did it watching a tutorial not my own per say lol

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap everything into a `SingleChildScrollView`

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: MyBigMessedView(),
)
```

Just make sure, that you have `phyics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` in your nested `ListView` if you have some.

Also, don't use Expanded as every parent widget.

Comment: Null check operator used on a null value
getting this error

Comment: where exactly do you get the null value?
You might get better help if you start with a simple WORKING example and then add components until it does NOT work anymore and finally describe your situation.